# Replace method not replacing text

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();   
sb.Append......   
var TheJs = sb.ToString();  
TheJs.Replace("'use strict';", "");
```

Basically, the text output still has the string `'use strict';` in it and I was wondering why?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx - string.Replace - "Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in the current instance are replaced with another specified string."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method returns a new string, it doesn't change the original one.

> **Returns a new string** in which all occurrences of a specified Unicode
>   character or String in the current string are replaced with another
>   specified Unicode character or String.

You should probably use;

```
TheJs = TheJs.Replace("'use strict';", "");
```

Strings are *[immutable types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)*. That's means you can't change them, even if you think you change them, you actually create a new string objects.

Answer (score 0):

you are just replacing it, not assigning the new value

```
TheJs = TheJs.Replace("'use strict';", "");
```

`String.Replace` method returns a new string, it doesn't change the original one.